# How to fix simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, woocommerce-rest-api

I am getting error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when trying to create a new woocommerce product using woocommerce rest api in my python project.

The error happens at `create_woocommerce_product_individually()` function

The urls passing to the photo_gallery_dictionary_list work fine.

```
def create_woocommerce_product_individually(wcapi_yachtcharterapp,mixed_name,fetched_sku,short_description,description,woo_commerce_category_id,photo_gallery_dictionary_list):

    data = {
            "name": mixed_name,
            "sku": fetched_sku,
            "images": photo_gallery_dictionary_list
            }
    wcapi_yachtcharterapp.post("products",data).json()
```

Traceback:

```
    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_management/intranet/views.py" in update_woo_products_from_mmk_yachts_massive
      1651.             update_woo_products_from_mmk_yachts_individual(mmk_yacht)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_management/intranet/views.py" in update_woo_products_from_mmk_yachts_individual
      1573.         create_woocommerce_product_individually(wcapi_yachtcharterapp,mixed_name,fetched_sku,short_description,description,woo_commerce_category_id,photo_gallery_dictionary_list)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_management/intranet/views.py" in create_woocommerce_product_individually
      1107.     wcapi_yachtcharterapp.post("products",data).json()

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py" in json
      897.         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py" in loads
      525.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in decode
      370.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

    File "/www/wwwroot/yachts_management/yachts_manage_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in raw_decode
      400.         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

    Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /private/update_woo_products_from_mmk_yachts_massive/
    Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: During `post`, if you are posting json data, use `json` kwargs: `wcapi_yachtcharterapp.post("products", json=data).json()`

Comment: @AKS when i apply this , i get the error put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
This is not the case.

Comment: I think it all depends on how `wcapi_yachtcharterapp` is designed.

Comment: wcapi_yachtcharterapp is just a call to my wordpress woocommerce api. Nothing spesial with that. Here is the woocommerce rest api documentation : https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` means the json decoder was given an empty string . Check the input to make sure it has content.